# Tired of copying node_modules to wwwroot folder

Tags: asp.net, gulp, wwwroot

I have an ASP.NET 5 project with a plenty of Node.js modules. They are installed under the `node_modules` folder.

In the development environment (environment=development), I started copying all the modules to `wwwroot\lib` manually. When that became tedious, I wrote a Gulp task to copy them. Now there are plenty of tasks.

Is there any ASP.NET project setting so the modules can be loaded from the `node_modules` folder at the root rather than from the `wwwroot\lib`?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** For development purposes, just add one more `UseStaticFiles` middleware. To your `Startup.cs` -> `public void Configure()` method -> Add this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"node_modules")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/node_modules")
});
```

`UseStaticFiles` is used twice. First, to serve static files from a default `wwwroot` and the second time to serve `/node_modules` files. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files).

Just be careful in production environment.

Answer (score 3):

There should be a `package.json` file in the same directory with that `node_modules`, you only need to copy it to the new location then run `npm install` from the command-line to install the packages. Then the new modules will soon be available at the new location.